# Spring Caching - ignore parameter for key

Tags: spring, caching, key, spring-cache

I want to cache the results of a simple getter that has an optional parameter (user-agent in the example below). How can I instruct the key to be created without taking into consideration the optional user-agent parameter?

```
@Cacheable(value="bookCache")
public Book getBooks(@RequestHeader(value = "user-agent", required = false) String userAgent) 
...
```

Comment: what about providing a custom `KeyGenerator`?

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One could customize how a key for a certain cache-object is created by providing a custom [`KeyGenerator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/KeyGenerator.html).

Here's what it could look:

```
@Service
class BookService {

    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "books", keyGenerator = "customKeyGenerator")
    public List<Book> getBooks(String someParam) {
        //....
    }
 }

@Component
class CustomKeyGenerator implements KeyGenerator {

    @Override
    public Object generate(Object target, Method method, Object... params) {

        // ... return a custom key
    }
}
```

### Custom key using SpEL

As Igor stated, you might not need a custom keyGenerator implementation - you could either create a fixed key (see his answer) or use the [`SpEL`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#expressions) to create a custom cache key. In the following example, it uses the first method-argument as a key (see [`@Cacheable#key`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html#key--) for details):

```
@Service
class BookService {

    @Cacheable(cacheNames = "books", key = "#root.args[0]")
    public List<Book> getBooks(String requiredParam, String optionalParam) {
        //....
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 10):

You might not need to implement custom `KeyGenerator` just to ignore the optional **userAgent** method parameter. What you could do is just define your **key** attribute with some string value e.g. *"books"*:

```
@Cacheable(value="bookCache", key = "'books'")
public Book getBooks(@RequestHeader(value = "user-agent", required = false) String userAgent) {
    // ...
}
```

Then your values will be cached in **bookCache** cache region, under the **key** *"books"*.

Comment: This seems like a much simpler solution