# Exclude specific field from caching spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, cache-control

I am trying to exclude a specific parameter (param 4) from caching in my rest spring boot application

I am new to the caching and not sure how can we exclude the specific parameter from caching

```
@Override
@Cacheable(value = "mykey")
public MyResponse myMethod(RestTemplate restTemplate, String param1, String param2, String param3, String param4){
```

I am expecting the param 4 field to be excluded from the caching

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48405252/spring-caching-ignore-parameter-for-key

Comment: Ya i have seen that but it is little confusing to me as am not sure how a specific param is being ignored from caching? Like in my example code above i want to exclude param 4 to be excluded

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Key can be created using SpEL in `@Cacheable` annotation. Parameters can be accessed in SpEL using `#aX` X is index of argument. In this case.

`@Cacheable(value="mykey", key="#a1+#a2+#a3")`

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/annotation/Cacheable.html#key--